# Reversi move class

Tags: python, classes

I redid a Python Reversi move preview routine that is online. I could use comments about using Python better and/or better OOP design since the original did not use classes. There are three main classes:

1. `Board` for the Reversi board
2. `Location` to hold an x,y coordinate (0-7,0-7)
3. `Move` to store a location to put a disc on a board and how many discs would be affected by that move

I separated out `Move` because I would like to keep a sequence of `Move`s in memory to play forward or reverse. `Board` knows about where the discs are in two bitfields, one for each player, and knows how to turn over discs and return if a disc is at a location.

```
import unittest
import copy
from bitarray import bitarray

INITIAL_BOARD = """
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|B|W|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|W|B|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
"""

def other_player(playerId):
    return 'B' if playerId == 'W' else 'W'

class Location:
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.valid = True
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.offset = self.convertToOffset(self.x,self.y)

    def convertToOffset(self,x,y):
        if self.valid:
            self.valid = (x >= 0 and x <= 7 and y >= 0 and y <= 7)
        return x + y * 8

    def translate(self,dx,dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy
        self.offset = self.convertToOffset(self.x,self.y)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        else:
            return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

class Board:
    def __init__(self, board=INITIAL_BOARD):
        self.discs = self.parse_board(board)

    def make_bitstring(self,board,color_current):
        other_color = other_player(color_current)
        def parse_to_bit(square):
            if square == color_current:
                return '1'
            elif square == '_' or square == other_color:
                return '0'
            return ''
        return bitarray(''.join(map(parse_to_bit,board)))

    def parse_board(self,board):
        return (self.make_bitstring(board,'B'),
            self.make_bitstring(board,'W'))

    def show(self):
        print self.discs    

    def at(self, location, player):
        return location.valid and self.discs[int(player=='W')][location.offset]

    def empty(self, location):
        return not location.valid or (not self.at (location,'B') and not self.at (location,'W'))

    def turnoverDisc(self, location):
        offset = location.offset
        self.discs[0][offset], self.discs[1][offset] = self.discs[1][offset], self.discs[0][offset]

    def placeDisc(self, location, player):
        self.discs[int(player=='W')][location.offset] = 1

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        else:
            return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

class Move:
    def __init__(self, board, location, color_player):    
        self.location = location
        self.player = color_player
        self.board = board
        self.discDelta = self.makeDiscDelta()

    def makeDiscDelta(self):
        result = []
        other = other_player(self.player)
        if not self.board.empty(self.location):
            return result
        for dir in [(1,0),(1,-1),(0,-1),(-1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1),(0,1),(1,1)]:
            next_location = copy.copy(self.location)
            next_location.translate(dir[0],dir[1])
            dirDelta = []
            while self.board.at(next_location,other):
                dirDelta.append(copy.copy(next_location))
                next_location.translate(dir[0],dir[1])
            if self.board.at(next_location,self.player):
                result.extend(dirDelta)
        return result

    def makeBoard(self):
        result = copy.deepcopy(self.board)
        for location in self.discDelta:
            result.turnoverDisc(location)
        result.placeDisc(self.location,self.player)
        return result

class ReversiTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def testMovePreviewWhite(self):
        board = Board()
        location = Location(4,5)
        move = Move(board,location,'W')        
        self.assertEquals([Location(4,4)], move.discDelta)

    def testMovePreviewBlack(self):
        board = Board()
        location = Location(3,2)
        move = Move(board,location,'W')        
        self.assertEquals([Location(3,3)], move.discDelta)

    def testMove(self):
        board = Board()
        expected_board = """
            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
            |_|_|_|B|W|_|_|_|
            |_|_|_|W|W|_|_|_|
            |_|_|_|_|W|_|_|_|
            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
            |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
            """
        expected = Board(expected_board)
        location = Location(4,5)
        move = Move(board,location,'W') 
        result = move.makeBoard()
        self.assertEquals(expected, result)
        self.assertEquals(board, Board())
        self.assertEquals(location, Location(4,5))
```

Comment: You've combined the _representation_ of the reversi board with the _information_ contained in the board. It's a good idea to separate the two. The board good be represented as a 2d list, and to draw the _representation_ contained in `expected_board` for example, you would have a method called, say `drawBoard(data)`.

Comment: What I could do to address this is add parser and printer classes for creating a board and display output of the board. I don't completely understand the problem though. The final representation I am planning on is html. expected_board is just for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import unittest
import copy
from bitarray import bitarray

INITIAL_BOARD = """
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|B|W|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|W|B|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
"""

def other_player(playerId):
    return 'B' if playerId == 'W' else 'W'

class Location:
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
```

Put spaces after commas: `def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):`

```
        self.valid = True
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.offset = self.convertToOffset(self.x,self.y)

    def convertToOffset(self,x,y):
```

Call it `convert_to_offset`, in accordance with the rest of this code (and PEP 8).

```
        if self.valid:
            self.valid = (x >= 0 and x <= 7 and y >= 0 and y <= 7)
```

This can be simplified a little using Python's operator chaining: `0 <= x <= 7 and 0 <= y <= 7`. But why is this method changing `self.valid`, when it doesn't change `self.x` or `self.y`? Make `self.valid` into a property, and `convert_to_offset` into a static method.

```
        return x + y * 8

    def translate(self,dx,dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy
        self.offset = self.convertToOffset(self.x,self.y)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        else:
            return False
```

`return NotImplemented` instead of `False` - that way, Python will try (the equivalent of) `other.__eq__(self)` and only give `False` if that is also `NotImplemented`. `False` means "I know that these two are not equal"; `NotImplemented` means "I don't know how to compare them".

```
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
```

First, this should be `not self == other`, because of the same comparison sequence above. But more importantly, this is the *default behavior* for `self != other`, so you might as well omit it.

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, board=INITIAL_BOARD):
        self.discs = self.parse_board(board)

    def make_bitstring(self,board,color_current):
        other_color = other_player(color_current)
        def parse_to_bit(square):
            if square == color_current:
                return '1'
            elif square == '_' or square == other_color:
                return '0'
            return ''
```

Consider moving this function up to module level and passing the colours into it (or, if you really feel like it, use a class for the squares and make this a method on it; but that probably isn't overly worthwhile).

```
        return bitarray(''.join(map(parse_to_bit,board)))
```

Consider using a generator expression, especially if you're in Py2 where `map` builds a list (at least use `itertools.imap` there) - but I'm quite sure I'm not alone in finding `return bitarray(''.join(parse_to_bit(square) for square in board))` more direct and easier to read.

```
    def parse_board(self,board):
        return (self.make_bitstring(board,'B'),
            self.make_bitstring(board,'W'))

    def show(self):
        print self.discs    

    def at(self, location, player):
        return location.valid and self.discs[int(player=='W')][location.offset]
```

Consider putting spaces around the `==`; but more importantly, there's no need to call `int` here - bools work fine as sequence indexes (in fact, bool is a subclass of int - you can even add and multiply them).

```
    def empty(self, location):
        return not location.valid or (not self.at (location,'B') and not self.at (location,'W'))
```

Do put spaces between arguments (after the commands), don't between the function name (`self.at`) and the opening bracket.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. I agree the location class needs to be reorganized and the spacing and case should be fixed. I need to experiment much later to see a difference in changing to a generator in the string parser instead of imap. I will certainly try out the default not equals and remove the int casts.